# About some proofs using epsilon notation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

There are many proofs in analysis where we find something like: "M=epsilon. This equality holds for any epsilon>0. So M=0.".

What is the background of this conclusion? Maybe I took the text out of context. I don't know.

For example this one:

[image]

Or this one:

[image]

Comment: Could you give a specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is more like "$M\leq\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$". That is, for any $\varepsilon$ we have that $M$ is smaller than any positive real number. Now what is the largest nonnegative real number that is smaller than any $\varepsilon>0$? Note that it is important that $M$ is nonnegative. otherwise the reasoning would not be correct

Comment: I think I grasp the idea. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds reasonable for me. And it seems to be the reason for this conclusion. But I am confused because initially we said that "epsilon>0" and then say "epsilon=0". Maybe this "zero" is not "our" zero? Maybe we mean some "number" which smaller than any possible number?

Comment: I guess you refer to your second example? Indeed, I'd not state it like that but instead write "Since the inequality holds for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have that $\mu^*\left(\bigcup_iA_i\right)\leq \sum_i\mu^*(A_i)$.

Comment: just think about that the inequality would also hold if we would chose $\varepsilon=100$. But we can make the inequality mich sharper by choosing $\varepsilon=1$, and yet we can make it sharper. So a natural question to ask for which value is the inequality the sharpest, which leads to the question asked in my answer